# Getting wrong Output from PostgreSQL Procedure/Function in Django API

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I have my database and all its procedures ready in PostgreSQL. I previously used Laravel as backend of my API and all the procedures were working correctly and returning the correct output.

My Laravel controller function for one of the API call is as follow:

```
public function retrieve() {
    $data = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM showallmenuitem()"));
    $status = count($data);

    return $status ? response(['message'=>'Menu item retrieved successfully','data' =>$data],200):response(['message'=>'Failed to retrieve menu item.']);
}
```

This method calls `showallmenuitem()` procedure and the output stored in the `$data` variable is as follow:

```json
{
    "message": "Menu item retrieved successfully",
    "data": [
        {
            "meniuid": 1,
            "menuitemsname": "User"
        },
        {
            "meniuid": 2,
            "menuitemsname": "Payment"
        }
    ]
}
```

But recently I changed my backend from Laravel to Django because I need some AI functionality in my app and AI models I need are written in python. So I created a simple view to call the same procedure from Django. I was expecting the same output as Laravel but Django is giving me Output in wrong format. I'm using psycopg2 as database drivers.
Here is my Django view code:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def retrieve(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.callproc("showallmenuitem")
            results = cursor.fetchall()

        response = {
            'message'       :   'Menu items retrieved successfully',
            'data'          :   results
            }

        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False, status= 200)
```

And I got output in following format:

```json
{
    "message": "Menu items retrieved successfully",
    "data": [
        [
            1,
            "User"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "Payment"
        ],
    ]
}
```

> `Note:` I have also tried running `execute` function instead of `callproc` as written below and still get the same output.

```py
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM showallmenuitem()")
            results = cursor.fetchall()
```

So my question is how to get output in proper json format in Django, like I get from Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `psycopg2` returns a list of tuples, which you see converted into `JSON` as an array of arrays. To change this see here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/

> Executing custom SQL directly

> By default, the Python DB API will return results without their field names, which means you end up with a list of values, rather than a dict. At a small performance and memory cost, you can return results as a dict by using something like this:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```